# Sparse and Tril functions exceptions

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, minimum-spanning-tree

Can anyone explain me why the code below doesnt work and returns me

```
W = [.34 .34 ];
DG = sparse([1 2],[2 3],W);

UG = tril(DG + DG')
```

**??? Error using ==> plus
Matrix dimensions must agree.**

and the code below works properly ?

```
W = [.34 .34 .34];
DG = sparse([1 2 3],[2 3 1],W);
UG = tril(DG + DG')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, the size of `DG` is 2 by 3 and therefore adding `DG` and `DG'` will cause an matrix dimension error. In the second example the matrix `DG` is 3 by 3, hence no error when adding `DG + DG'`.

Comment: Thanks! I observed that this only works if the max element of two vectors exists both to the first and the second vector.